# Linear/Order Preserving Clustering in Python

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, k-means

I want to group numbers in a list, based on how 'large' the numbers are in comparison of their neighbors, but I want to do it continuously and via clustering if possible. To clarify, let me give you an example:

Suppose you have the list

```
lst = [10, 11.1, 30.4, 30.0, 32.9, 4.5, 7.2]
```

then, if we have 3 groups, it's obvious how to cluster. Running the k-means algorithm from sklearn (see code) confirms this. But, when the numbers in the list aren't that 'convenient',  I run into trouble. Suppose you have the list:

```
lst = [10, 11.1, 30.4, 30.0, 32.9, 6.2, 31.2, 29.8, 12.3, 10.5]
```

My problem now is two-fold:

1. I want some sort of 'order-preserving, linear' clustering, which takes the order of the data into account. For the list above, the clustering algorithm should give me a desired output of the form

   ```
   lst = [0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2]
   ```
2. If you look at this output above, you also see that I want the value 6.2 to be clustered in the second cluster, i.e. I want the cluster algorithm to see it as an outlier, not as an entirely new cluster.
3. **EDIT** For clarification, I want to be able to specify the amount of clusters in the linear clustering process, i.e. the 'end total' of clusters.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

lst = [10, 11.1, 30.4, 30.0, 32.9, 4.5, 7.2]

km = KMeans(3,).fit(np.array(lst).reshape(-1,1))
print(km.labels_)
# [0 0 1 1 1 2 2]: OK output

lst = [10, 11.1, 30.4, 30.0, 32.9, 6.2, 31.2, 29.8, 12.3, 10.5]
km = KMeans(3,).fit(np.array(lst).reshape(-1,1))
print(km.labels_)
# [0 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 0]. Desired output: [0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2]
```

Comment: the way i see it, why dont you get the normal cluster output first, and then coerce it into the manner you see fit?

Comment: @ParitoshSingh, the only way I can see that work is to do it manually and because I have many lists, I'm looking for a way to do this unsupervised.

Comment: oh, no, not manual. If you are okay with the solution sometimes messing up (as any machine learning tool can at the end of the day), you should be able to code something. Let me see if i can cook up a prototype.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, i think a straightforward(ish) way to get the desired results is to just use a normal K-means clustering, and then modify the generated output as desired.
**Explanation:** The idea is to get the K-means outputs, and then iterate through them: keeping track of previous item's cluster group, and current cluster group, and controlling new clusters created on conditions. Explanations in code.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

lst = [10, 11.1, 30.4, 30.0, 32.9, 4.5, 7.2]

km = KMeans(3,).fit(np.array(lst).reshape(-1,1))
print(km.labels_)
# [0 0 1 1 1 2 2]: OK output

lst = [10, 11.1, 30.4, 30.0, 32.9, 6.2, 31.2, 29.8, 12.3, 10.5]
km = KMeans(3,).fit(np.array(lst).reshape(-1,1))
print(km.labels_)
# [0 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 0]. Desired output: [0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2]


def linear_order_clustering(km_labels, outlier_tolerance = 1):
    '''Expects clustering outputs as an array/list'''
    prev_label = km_labels[0] #keeps track of last seen item's real cluster
    cluster = 0 #like a counter for our new linear clustering outputs
    result = [cluster] #initialize first entry
    for i, label in enumerate(km_labels[1:]):
        if prev_label == label: 
            #just written for clarity of control flow, 
            #do nothing special here
            pass 
        else: #current cluster label did not match previous label
            #check if previous cluster label reappears 
            #on the right of current cluster label position 
            #(aka current non-matching cluster is sandwiched 
            #within a reasonable tolerance)
            if (outlier_tolerance and 
                prev_label in km_labels[i + 1: i + 2 + outlier_tolerance]):                     label = prev_label #if so, overwrite current label
            else:
                cluster += 1 #its genuinely a new cluster
        result.append(cluster)
        prev_label = label
    return result
```

Note that i have only tested this with tolerance for 1 outlier, and cannot promise it works as-is out of the box for all cases. This should get you started however.

Output:

```
print(km.labels_)
result = linear_order_clustering(km.labels_)
print(result)
[1 1 0 0 0 2 0 0 1 1]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2]
```

Comment: unless I'm mistaken, you can now end up with more clusters than initially given as input?

Comment: yep, as is necessary for linear clustering. essentially, a group such as `[0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0]` would necessarily be grouped  into 3 linear clusters.

Comment: I see, maybe I should've been more clear: I want to be able to specify the amount of clusters we end up with (so *after* the linear clustering).  Any idea what would be the most efficient way? I can't imagine a for-loop of some sorts being the best solution.

Comment: ah right, that makes sense. in that case, unless you want to simply work with an iterative solution (choosing lesser and lesser clusters for the initial k means clustering and seeing number of final clusters after linear order clustering), You may have design a custom clustering solution. Alternatively, you can actually modify the current output to get your desired output, by just taking the outputs at this step and merging clusters which are closest to each other (but only checking adjacent clusters for merge-candidates)

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this in a couple of passes.  First I would have a first function/method to do the analysis to determine the clustering centers, for each group and return an array of those centers.  I would then take those centers along with the list into another function/method to assemble a list of the cluster id of each number in the list.  I would then return that list sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Define a threshold.

If the values of x[i] and x[i-1] differ too much, begin a new *segment*.

For better results, look at KDE and CUSUM approaches.

Don't use clustering. It has a different objective.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and solved it as follows:

- Given a distances matrix between all the elements,
- I either do a bottom-up clustering (merging the two "most similar" elements/sub-clusters) or a top-down clustering (splitting a group of elements into the "most different" sub-clusters);
- To compute the distance between sub-clusters I aggregate the distances of all the elements in them (the default method is taking the average, using the minimal or maximal distance is also possible).
- Either way this results in a hierarchical clustering which you can then cut to produce any desired number of clusters.

It seems the bottom-up method gave better results, but YMMV.

Here's the code for the bottom-up method (in R). It builds:

- A `merge` matrix where every row includes two columns with the indices of the next two things to merge - negative index for elements and positive index for previously created sub-clusters (R uses 1-based indices)
- A `height` array containing the distance between the two merged elements/sub-clusters. This is added to the maximal height of the merged things (0 height for leaf elements) so heights are always increasing (for display of the tree, or as R calls it, the "dendogram").

This can be used to create R `hclust` objects which can be displayed and manipulated in various ways.

This isn't the most efficient possible implementation, but it gets the work done in a reasonable amount of time. A more efficient approach would be to reduce the size of the distances matrix (this would require more book keeping keeping track of the indices mapping between the smaller matrix and the original elements):

```
bottom_up <- function(distances, aggregation) {
    aggregate <- switch(aggregation, mean=mean, min=min, max=max)

    rows_count <- dim(distances)[1]
    diag(distances) <- Inf

    merge <- matrix(0, nrow=rows_count - 1, ncol=2)
    height <- rep(0, rows_count - 1)
    merged_height <- rep(0, rows_count)
    groups <- -(1:rows_count)

    for (merge_index in 1:(rows_count - 1)) {
        adjacent_distances <- pracma::Diag(distances, 1)

        low_index <- which.min(adjacent_distances)
        high_index <- low_index + 1

        grouped_indices <- sort(groups[c(low_index, high_index)])

        merged_indices <- which(groups %in% grouped_indices)
        groups[merged_indices] <- merge_index
        merge[merge_index,] <- grouped_indices

        height[merge_index] <- max(merged_height[merged_indices]) + adjacent_distances[low_index]
        merged_height[merged_indices] <- height[merge_index]

        merged_distances <- apply(distances[,merged_indices], 1, aggregate)
        distances[,merged_indices] <- merged_distances
        distances[merged_indices,] <- rep(merged_distances, each=length(merged_indices))

        distances[merged_indices, merged_indices] <- Inf
    }

    return (list(merge=merge, height=height))
}
```

The `pracma::Diag(distances, 1)` fetches the offset-by-1 diagonal (above the main diagonal).