# Segmenting a vector into n "similar" segments in R/python

Tags: python, r, algorithm, cluster-analysis

If I have a vector of *m* real numbers, how can I split the vector into n segments, such that each segment contains "similar" values, all with adjacent positions in the original vector?

"Similar" here could refer to minimising the variability of the numbers in each segment. So, e.g. if I have the vector: `[4, 4.2, 4, 18, 1, 2, 0.98, 15, 17]`, and I want to split it into 4 (chosen randomly for the sake of the example) segments, I would end up with the segments: `{[4, 4.2, 4], [18], [1, 2, 0.98],[15, 17]}`.

*Notably, similarity doesn't have to be defined as minimal variability, but that is just what makes sense to me*.

So my questions are:

1. Is there an algorithm that, given a vector of size *m*, and a number *n* (where *n* ≤ *m*) of segments to split that vector into, can find the optimal m segments, such that each section contains "similar" numbers? The aim here could be to minimise the sum of the variances of each segment.
2. Is there an algorithm that can do the above, but without taking in the number of segments as an argument, and can instead find an optimal number of segments, and their positioning? (In my mind, the optimal number of segments would just be m segments, since each segment would have a variability of 0, so there would have to be some sort of cost function associated with adding a new segment).

I would ideally like answers in R or python, however, I'm mostly just interested in the logic/names of such algorithms.

Comment: First you need to define a function you want to optimize. Maybe the sum of the variances of  segements? That is not clearly defined in your question. For case 2. all segments have only one element would always be optimal (varanc of 0 in each segegment) ;-) So you may need an  other value to define 'optimal' for this case.

Comment: Yes that's true. It makes sense to me to minimise the sum of the variances of each segment. I've added this to the original question.

This being said, in case two, there would then have to be a cost function associated with adding a new segment. But I am not sure how to define this cost function given that I can't play around with an algorithm to perform case 1 yet.

Comment: Similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54349503/linear-order-preserving-clustering-in-python).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a greedy algorithm that initializes the splits at the greatest absolute differences between consecutive points then checks whether swapping one of the current split points with an unchecked potential split point results in a smaller sum of squared differences from the group means. It continues to do this until no more one-to-one swaps result in a smaller sum of squared differences.

```
library(Rfast) # for `nth`

segment <- function(x, k) {
  n <- length(x)
  cs <- cumsum(x)
  k1 <- k - 1L

  fcost <- function(v) {
    k <- diff(c(0, v, n))
    sum((rep.int(diff(c(0, cs[v], cs[n]))/k, k) - x)^2)
  }
  
  v <- sort(nth(abs(diff(x)), k1, k1, TRUE, TRUE))
  mincost <- fcost(v)
  vv <- v
  cont <- TRUE
  
  while(cont) {
    cont <- FALSE
    
    for (i in sample((1:(n - 1L))[-v])) {
      sub <- FALSE
      
      for (j in 1:k1) {
        vv[j] <- i
        currcost <- fcost(sort(vv))
        
        if (currcost < mincost) {
          sub <- TRUE
          mincost <- currcost
          jj <- j
        }
        
        vv[j] <- v[j]
      }
      
      if (sub) {
        sub <- FALSE
        v[jj] <- vv[jj] <- i
        cont <- TRUE
      }
    }
  }
  
  split(x, rep.int(1:k, diff(c(0, sort(v), n))))
}
```

Testing:

```
segment(x, 4)
#> $`1`
#> [1] 4.0 4.2 4.0
#> 
#> $`2`
#> [1] 18
#> 
#> $`3`
#> [1] 1.00 2.00 0.98
#> 
#> $`4`
#> [1] 15 17
```

Some code that could be used to run additional tests:

```
set.seed(1025554475)
(k <- sample(sample(10, 1)))
#> [1] 8 7 4 3 1 2 5 6
x <- lapply(k, \(k) rnorm(sample(100, 1), k))
y <- segment(unlist(x), length(k))
i <- split(1:sum(lengths(x)), rep.int(1:length(k), lengths(y)))
plot(unlist(x))
for (j in 1:length(k)) points(i[[j]], y[[j]], col = j)
```

The segments are different from the "true" segments:

```
unname(lengths(x))
#> [1]  4 53 77  9 19 99 76 50
unname(lengths(y))
#> [1] 57 86 22 48  3 45 76 50
```

But the sum of the squared differences is lower for the segments returned by `segment`:

```
sum(sapply(x, \(z) sum((z - mean(z))^2)))
#> [1] 367.4558
sum(sapply(y, \(z) sum((z - mean(z))^2)))
#> [1] 359.605
```

---

For an interesting case that demonstrates that `segment` can return a local optimum and can also return different results for the same input (due to `for (i in sample((1:(n - 1L))[-v]))`, which randomizes the order in which the split points are checked):

```
set.seed(1190862002)
k <- sample(sample(2:10, 1))
x <- lapply(k, \(k) rnorm(sample(100, 1), k))
sum(sapply(x, \(z) sum((z - mean(z))^2)))
#> [1] 249.6061
replicate(10, sum(sapply(segment(unlist(x), length(k)), \(z) sum((z - mean(z))^2))))
#>  [1] 250.2619 250.2619 250.2619 252.2920 250.2619 252.2920 245.7726 250.2619
#>  [9] 245.7726 252.2920
```

Answer (score 1):

***If your vector is not long***, I think ***brute-force*** approaches are also considerably effective and straightforward. Below is one of the brute-force instance

```
f <- function(v, n) {
    g <- rep(0, length(v))
    lst <- combn(
        length(v) - 1,
        n - 1,
        \(x) split(v, cumsum(replace(g, x + 1, 1))),
        simplify = FALSE
    )
    lst[[which.min(sapply(lst, \(x) sum(sapply(x, var), na.rm = TRUE)))]]
}
```

and we will see

```
> v <- c(4, 4.2, 4, 18, 1, 2, 0.98, 15, 17)

> n <- 4

> f(v,n)
$`0`
[1] 4.0 4.2 4.0

$`1`
[1] 18

$`2`
[1] 1.00 2.00 0.98

$`3`
[1] 15 17
```

Answer (score 0):

Package {[anticlust](https://github.com/m-Py/anticlust)}

> partitions a pool of elements into clusters (or anticlusters) with the goal of achieving high between-cluster similarity and high within-cluster heterogeneity.

... and offers variance as one of the similarity measures.

In your example you could thus:

create your vector `v` ...

```
v <- c(4, 4.2, 4, 18, 1, 2, 0.98, 15, 17)
```

... and retrieve group indices for e.g. 4 groups of similar variance:

```
library(anticlust)
group <- anticlustering(v, K = 4, objective = 'variance')
```

result, with some data tidying:

```
library(dplyr)
data.frame(v, group) |>
  mutate(var = var(v), .by = group) |>
  arrange(group)
```

```
      v group      var
1  4.00     1  76.0000
2 18.00     1  76.0000
3  2.00     1  76.0000
4  4.20     2   0.0200
5  4.00     2   0.0200
6  1.00     3  98.0000
7 15.00     3  98.0000
8  0.98     4 128.3202
9 17.00     4 128.3202
```

Group (segment) 2 still deviates a lot from the others; I guess that's as good as it gets with that large overall CV and only nine elements to move about.

---

**Edit**

To *minimize* within-group variance instead, you can cluster with [Ward's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ward%27s_method) (`v` as above):

```
data.frame(value = v,
           group = v |>
             dist() |>
             hclust(method = 'ward.D') |>
             cutree(4)
           ) |> 
  mutate(var = var(value), .by = group) |>
  arrange(group)
```

```
  value group        var
1  4.00     1 0.01333333
2  4.20     1 0.01333333
3  4.00     1 0.01333333
4 18.00     2 0.50000000
5 17.00     2 0.50000000
6  1.00     3 0.34013333
7  2.00     3 0.34013333
8  0.98     3 0.34013333
9 15.00     4         NA
```

Comment: This seems to perform something different. From my understanding, this algorithm tries to maximise similarity between groups. So if using the 'variance' objective, with `K=4` partitions, it will try to create 4 segments, each of similar variance.

What I want instead is the opposite, 4 groups, each with minimal variance.

An example of this is given the vector `[1,1,1,2,2]` split into two partitions, I would expect the partitions to be `[1,1,1]` and `[2,2]`, however this returns `[1,1,2]` and `[1,2]`. It also does not preserve the order of elements in the original vector.

Answer (score 0):

## Idea (Recursion)

If you would like to use the sum of variances as the cost function, I guess you can define a recursive function to calculate the sum cost.

Assuming we have a recursion function `f` that solves the problem, i.e., computing the minimal cost, the logic of the recursion can be briefly written as (`v` is the vector and `n` is the number of desired segments)

```
f(v, n) = min{f(v[1:k], 1} + f(v[-(1:k)], n-1))} for all 1<=k<=length(v)-1
```

where `f(v,1) = var(v)` as the initial cost computation since we have a single segment. Another fact we should take into account is that `f(v,1)==0` if `length(v)==1`, which corresponding to the scenario of one segment consisting of one single value.

*It should be noted that the computing time explosively increases as the number of segments grows, since we exponentially increase the number of searching in `min` (here `min` is a **non-linear** operator, which goes through all available `k`s in `1<=k<=length(v)-1`) per iteration of recursions.*

## Code

According to the recursion analysis shown above, one implementation is given as below

```
f <- function(v, n) {
    # recursive function that pursues the global minimal cost
    helper <- function(v, n) {
        if (n == 1) {
            return(list(
                cost = ifelse(length(v) == 1, 0, var(v)),
                grpsz = length(v)
            ))
        }
        if (length(v) == 1) {
            return(list(cost = 0, grpsz = 1))
        }
        s <- Inf
        for (k in 1:(length(v) - 1)) {
            a <- Recall(v[1:k], 1)
            b <- Recall(v[-(1:k)], n - 1)
            u <- a$cost + b$cost
            if (u <= s) {
                s <- u
                p <- c(k, b$grpsz)
            }
        }
        list(cost = s, grpsz = p)
    }

    # calculate the splits
    sp <- helper(v, n)
    k <- cumsum(sp$grpsz) + 1
    list(
        cost = sp$cost,
        segments = split(v, cumsum(replace(rep(0, length(v)), k[k <= length(v)], 1)))
    )
}
```

and the return value is a list, consisting of two domains: `cost` is the sum of the variances of each segments, and `grpsz` is the sizes of each consecutive segments. For example, regarding the data `[4, 4.2, 4, 18, 1, 2, 0.98, 15, 17]` in the question, the value of computed `grpsz` is `c(3,1,3,2)`, which indicates the size distribution of desired `4` segments.

## Example

```
> f(v, 4)
$cost
[1] 2.353467

$segments
$segments$`0`
[1] 4.0 4.2 4.0

$segments$`1`
[1] 18

$segments$`2`
[1] 1.00 2.00 0.98

$segments$`3`
[1] 15 17
```

Another test for checking if the order of elements in segments keeps the same as in the original vector

```
> set.seed(0)

> k <- 5

> x <- rnorm(40)

> y <- unname(unlist(f(x, k)$segments))

> all.equal(x, y)
[1] TRUE
```